# Как сделать остановку персонажа Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проект 2D. Персонаж двигается вверх и вниз. Гравитация на нуле, так как движение идет и вверх (платформер с видом сферху). Персонаж двигается бесконечно без остановки, останавливается при столкновении с другим объектом. Как сделать так, чтобы если кнопка не нажата, то персонаж останавливается?

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player_Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D RigBud;
    public float movespeed;
    public float jumpheight;
    public bool jump;
    public LayerMask WoIG;

    void Start()
    {
        RigBud = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            RigBud.velocity = new Vector2(RigBud.velocity.x, jumpheight);
            Debug.Log("Up");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            RigBud.velocity = new Vector2(RigBud.velocity.x, -jumpheight);
            Debug.Log("Down");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно установить скорость в ноль, если на объект не действует больше никаких сил.

```
void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
     {
          RigBud.velocity = new Vector2(RigBud.velocity.x, jumpheight);
          Debug.Log("Up");
     }

    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        RigBud.velocity = new Vector2(RigBud.velocity.x, -jumpheight);
        Debug.Log("Down");
    }
    else
    {
        RigBud.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}
```